# Show answers in review for question closures

Tags: feature-request, review

When reviewing question closure proposals, I'd like a way to be able to see answers to the question without having to leave the review page.  This is primarily useful for borderline questions where "Has the question generated any answers of value?" can be a deciding factor.

Comment: Closing a question doesn't delete existing answers, and doesn't prevent them from being voted on or closed.  Closing a question simply prevents the adding of additional answers.  Given that, how does knowing if there are existing answers, or what they are, inform that decision?

Comment: It gives an indication of what other answers the question might generate.  If a question looks like it *might* not be a good fit for the site, but it's generating good quality answers, it may be worth keeping as-is.  If it's generating a lot of noise however, then it definitely needs some action.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of questions for which your decision to close would be influenced by the answers?  I just don't see the guidelines for whether or not a question should be closed as being in any way dependent on the answers.

Comment: A good example is this one:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82146/how-do-i-earn-reaper-energy-if-ive-sold-my-grim-reaper-talsiman  The new question asks about a specific situation, which is not called out in the text of the proposed duplicate question.  The questions themselves were not *exact* duplicates, but answers in the latter *may* (if written comprehensively instead of generally) address the former.  I had to actually go and review answers to the proposed duplicate, to see if the special case asked about in the new question was actually addressed.

Comment: As it turns out, it seems some answers did address the special case - although not quite in an obvious way.

Comment: I would say that the questions aren't duplicates.  Just because the answer for some other question also contains the information needed to answer other questions doesn't make the questions duplicates.  The question should not be closed.  If the proposed dup has the answer it should be linked to, and the relevant sections paraphrased or quoted.

Comment: @Servy But that's exactly *why* the questions are duplicate.  If all you're going to do is quote or paraphrase answers from the other question, the duplicate should be closed and made to serve as a link to that question.  It also helps the asker and future readers to be further educated by the other aspects which are in-scope of the broader question but out-of-scope of the newer one.  In my experience, this is a pretty common practice on StackExchange.

Comment: Just because answers are the same, or similar, doesn't mean the questions are the same.  Here, the answers won't even be the same.  One is a more general question, another is a more specific question with the answer buried in the explanation of the more general one.  Since it would only be quoting a small snippet, and not the entire thing, it pushes it from borderline to not a dupe in my eyes.